# Maven - invalid target release 1.7 with Java 1.7

Tags: java, maven

Everything seems correct, but it just won't work.

```
$ sudo mvn clean package
...
[INFO] Compilation failure
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid target release: 1.7
```

Versions :

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 20:16:01+0100)
Java version: 1.7.0_75
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For the record :

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But I don't think this is the problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: The answer is correct. Just to add some info: Java 7 was released on July 28, 2011. The version 2.0.2 of the maven-compiler-plugin is dated Feb 13, 2007. See the problem?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo mvn ...` instead of simply `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Why are you using Maven 2.2.1? Hint: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-announce/201503.mbox/%3C20150320213920.6AE4B17423%40minotaur.apache.org%3E

Comment: @khmarbaise mvn needs to delete `classes` folder. It gives an error if I don't use sudo. But that's not the problem

Comment: But sudo influences Environment which mean for the sudo use not correctly set...? Apart from that mvn clean will delete the whole `target` folder and not only `target/classes`...

Comment: @khmarbaise Holy shirt you're right !! When I did `sudo mvn -v` it gave me java version 1.6 ... who would've known... oh right ! You ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mvn clean` removes `target` folder which is read only.
Solution : Use `sudo` right ? Except that `sudo` no longer reads your variables or PATH but those of **super user**

`sudo mvn -v` now shows Java 1.6

Big thanks to khmarbaise

Answer (score 1):

Try updating compiler plugin. Version `3.3` is the latest. If that does not help try using Maven 3+

Comment: Same error, different way of saying it : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

Comment: so it looks like `org.apache.maven.MavenCli` was compiles with java7 but you want to run it with java6 or below. Please check what is your `JAVA_HOME` env variable and if you override it somewhere in your project. You can also edit `mvn` script to print out the commands which are executed to build your project.'

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the configuration for [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Best is to configure this within a pluginManagement area.